# Isn't relative padding supported in table columns?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am trying to generate a report using html tables. I want the first column to have a 12%-padding on the left side. Setting this padding causes the column to overlap, even there is a lot of free space:
[image: overlapping cells]

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/7gbyq3or/):

```
table {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

table th,
table td {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

table td:first-child,
table th:first-child {
    padding-left: 12%;
}
```

Using a fixed padding or using an empty column with a 12%-width is just working fine. The table is also displayed correctly after resizing the browser window.

Does anyone have a idea what is going on here?

Answer (score 1):

It's because of the [box model](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp).

> The percentage is calculated with respect to the width of the
>   generated box's containing box. If the containing block's width
>   depends on this element, then the resulting layout is undefined in CSS
>   2.1.

Answer (score 0):

It's obvious that there's not enough space on smaller screen, that is why your text is pushed out of the cell. Add an empty cell with some width specified and use it as a spacer.
Something like:

```
<tr>
    <th class="spacer"></th>
    <th class="col-left first">Rank</th>
    <th class="col-left">Name</th>
    <th class="col-right">A</th>
    <th class="col-right">B</th>
    <th class="col-right">C</th>
    <th class="col-right">D</th>
    <th class="col-right">E</th>
    <th class="col-right">F</th>
    <th class="col-right">G</th>
    <th class="col-right">Sum</th>
</tr> 

.spacer {
  width: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding:

> width:

or

> min-width:

property to css

```
<th class="col-left first" id="space">Rank</th>
```

`#space{
  width:130px;
}`

Comment: adding padding implies that between the edge and the cell there is a space of this mode all the content moves to the right and when running out of space it overlaps, also the value is relative to its container, putting a fixed value can be a solution apart from defining enough space to the cell.